# Node.js getting SIGINT from pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm trying to use pm2 to run my node app as a service.

Right now, starting and stopping the app works. However, I want to do a graceful shutdown.

My app already listens for SIGINT, shutdowns the server and then exits the process. However, trying to put pm2 to send the SIGINT, just causes the app to restart, like if pm2 was killing and starting it again.

This is how I create the process:

> pm2 start server.js --name ProcessName --silent --kill-timeout 3000

Here's my app's code for listening the SIGINT:

```
process.on("SIGINT", function () {
    //graceful shutdown
    server.end().then(() => {
        process.exit();
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

});
```

Then to shutdown the app using pm2, I'm running:

> pm2 sendSignal SIGINT ProcessName

Which, again, restarts the app.

Reading over pm2 docs, I found that pm2 will also send a `shutdown` event to the app, so I added:

```
process.on('message', function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'shutdown') {
        server.end().then(() => {
            process.exit();
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Which isn't working either.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your code not crash when you start it normally? (Like `node server.js`)

Comment: No, it works perfectly fine. And it does catch the SIGINT when I press CTRL+C and exists gracefully (logs some output in the log files and everything).

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. Shutdown the app with `pm2 stop` instead. That sends sigint and doesn't restart it.

Comment: @ReverseCold already tried that. The stop commands sends a SIGINT but the app never gets it, it does stops the app, but not gracefully. Running pm2 monit you see that a SIGINT was sent. I’m thinking something weird happens and maybe the pm2 wrapper process is killed by the SIGINT instead of the app itself. I don’t know... trying to find an explanation.

Comment: Does starting the app the regular way and sending a sigint work?

Comment: Also you might want to try increasing your kill time. Perhaps `server.end` isn't finishing fast enough?

Comment: @ReverseCold running the app with node server.js and then hitting CTRL+C works. It sends a SIGINT signal and app shutsdows the way it should. Also tested increasing the kill time with like 3 minutes and it also doesn’t work.

Comment: So kill time = 3 minutes immediately kills it? Or does it wait the 3 minutes?

Comment: @ReverseCold it kills it immediately too.

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't solved it yet...

Based on the information you provided, I assume you are running it on Windows.

Your app cannot catch `SIGINT` sent by PM2 on Windows.
`shutdown` message works on windows too, but it is sent only by `gracefulReload` command.

---

(update)
These are not complete solutions, but might be helpful (hopefully...)

`sendSignal` command calls `process.kill()` eventually, and some of these [signals](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) might work (haven't tried).

I also found the below method. This can gracefully shutdown a process without restarting **only if** `autorestart` option is turned **off**.
And then your clusters will not reload in case of an accident, so it might not be what you want though...

pm2 lets you send a custom message ([reference](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/pm2-programmatic/#send-message-to-processes)).
Put the code below in a new file:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');
var id = process.argv[2];

pm2.connect(() => {
  pm2.sendDataToProcessId({
    type: 'shutdown',
    data:{some: 'data'},
    id: id,
    topic: 'some topic'
  }, (err, res) => {
    console.log('message sent');
    pm2.disconnect();

    if(err) throw err;
  })
});
```

Modify the part that listens the `shutdown` message like below:

```
process.on('message', function(msg){
  if(msg == 'shutdown' || msg.type == 'shutdown'){
    // code to clean up
  }
});
```

And run the first file with `node` with *id* of the cluster you want to shutdown as an argument.

The reason for extra `msg.type == 'shutdown'` in the condition is that `pm2.sendDataToProcessId()` requires the argument to be an object with those keys, and does not accept simple `shutdown` string.

Comment: But `gracefulReload` will reload the app after catching the shutdown, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. It didn't?

Comment: That's the thing. I don't want to restart it. I want to gracefully shut it down.

Comment: @FedeE. did you manage to get a solution to this working in the end? I'm facing the same thing. I could go down the custom message route, but interested to know if you found anything cleaner?

Comment: @Ian nope. I wans't able to find a solution for this.

Comment: @Toraja Do you have a reference for *"Your app cannot catch SIGINT sent by PM2 on Windows."* in the docs somewhere?  This seems to be a [reoccurring problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691598/graceful-shutdown-with-nodejs-pm2-sigint-not-working?noredirect=1#comment105539496_59691598).

Comment: @Reinstate Monica at the last part of this section: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events

Answer (score 1):

In general `pm2 stop` is the right way to stop your application. However if you run appliation inside of the Docker you need to use `pm2-runtime` instead of `pm2` which is a part of `pm2` npm package and passes system `SIGINT` to all child processes. See http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Catching the sigint and exiting gracefully should work in your first example.

To actually stop the server, use `pm2 stop` instead of `pm2 sendSignal SIGINT ProcessName`.

See http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/signals-clean-restart/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows servers, you may need to also catch `SIGBREAK`. Be sure to experiment with that as well as `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` for graceful shutdown.