# Graceful shutdown with nodejs pm2 SIGINT not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

Hello I Have an application server written in js and is running on windows. Furthermore I'm using pm2 module but I have noticed that when I start my application server via `pm2 start index.js -i 8` and then I want to stop all pm2 processes via `pm2 stop all` the event listeners for `SIGINT` are completely ignored...

I should add that this works fine when used with plain node and not pm2. So I was wondering am I missing something obvious here? Bellow is a sample test source and pm2 [docs](https://doc.pm2.io/en/runtime/best-practices/graceful-shutdown/)

```
const http = require('http'); 
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    response.end('Hello Node.js Server!'); 
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
    } 
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {

    console.log('NIX SIGINT!!!');

    process.exit(0);

});

process.on('message', (msg) => {

    if (msg == 'shutdown') {

            console.log('WIN SIGINT!!!');

            process.exit(0)

    } else {
        console.log('msg:', msg);
    }

});
```

**Update:**

Versions & OS

`OS: Windows`

`pm2 version: ^4.2.1`

`Nodejs version: v12.14.1`

pm2 logs

```
PM2      | App [grace:0] starting in -cluster mode-
PM2      | App [grace:0] online
0|grace  | server is listening on 3000
PM2      | Stopping app:grace id:0
PM2      | App name:grace id:0 disconnected
PM2      | App [grace:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | pid=10820 msg=process killed
```

Comment: Does `console.log('NIX SIGINT!!!');` log when you call `pm2 stop all`?

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607260/node-js-getting-sigint-from-pm2

Comment: @ReinstateMonica nope it does not. I Updated my quiestion.

Comment: ["Your app cannot catch SIGINT sent by PM2 on Windows."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50797542/10746224)

Comment: same doesn't work